# Class hierarchy in templated types in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, types

I am working on a simple project where there are publishers who read from one data source and construct events for subscribers to work on.

An event will have a unique ptr to the data and the subscribers will have a shared ptr to the event.

I want to have a common interface to an event so a subscriber can subscribe to an arbitrary Data publisher.
But a publisher can publish only one type of Data.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Data
{

};

class ChildData : public Data
{
};

template<typename T>
class Event
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> _data;
};

void someFunc(Event<Data> event)
{
    std::cout << "hello Word" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Event<ChildData> event();
    someFunc(event);
    return 0;
}
```

but am getting the following compiler error

```
/home/rory/dev/cpp_sandbox/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/rory/dev/cpp_sandbox/main.cpp:27:19: error: could not convert ‘event’ from ‘Event<ChildData> (*)()’ to ‘Event<Data>’
     someFunc(event);
                   ^
CMakeFiles/example.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/example.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/example.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is this sort of thing possible in C++?

Comment: First of all `Event<ChildData> event();` declares a *function* taking no argument and returning a `Event<ChildData>`. It does not declare a variable of type `Event<ChildData>`. This is known as "*most vexing parse*".   I don't think that is intended. Remove the `()` if you want to declare a default-constructed variable.

Comment: This approach isn't going to work. `Event<Data>` and `Event<ChildData>` are two distinct, unrelated classes, even though `ChildData` is derived from `Data`. `Event<Data>` is not the "common interface" you are looking for. If you want a common interface, define one (as a non-template class) and have `Event<T>` derive from it and implement its methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic line is this:

```
Event<ChildData> event();
```

Per the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) rule, this is interpreted as a function declaration. You can omit the parenthesis, if your `Event` class has a default constructor that initializes all members. Otherwise use uniform initialization syntax:

```
Event<ChildData> event{};
```

Also, you will likely have to use `std::move` to pass `event` to `someFunc`, since `Event` is not copyable because of the `std::unique_ptr` data member. Also, you will have to implement conversion from `Event<ChildData>` to `Event<Data>`, which is required for `someFunc`.

> I want to have a common interface to an event so a subscriber can subscribe to an arbitrary Data publisher. But a publisher can publish only one type of Data.

From this description, it looks like the `Event` template is superfluous. The common interface for `Data` descendants can be described in the `Data` class itself, so unless there is some need to separate event from data, it would be easier to deal just with data.

In order to discriminate different event types, you can use an enum.

```
enum class EventType
{
    A,
    B,
    C
};

class Data
{
private:
    const EventType m_type;

protected:
    explicit Data(EventType type) : m_type(type) {}

public:
    virtual ~Data() = default;

    // Prohibit copying to avoid accidental slicing
    Data(Data const&) = delete;
    Data& opreator= (Data const&) = delete;

    EventType get_type() const { return m_type; }
};

class ChildData :
    public Data
{
public:
    ChildData() : Data(EventType::A) {}
};

void receive(std::unique_ptr< Data > event)
{
    switch (event->get_type())
    {
    case EventType::A:
        {
            std::unique_ptr< ChildData > child_event{ static_cast< ChildData* >(event.release()) };
            // Process ChildData
        }
        break;

    case EventType::B:
        // ...
    case EventType::C:
        // ...
    }
}

void publish(std::unique_ptr< Data > event);

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr< ChildData > event{ new ChildData() };
    // Fill ChildData event
    publish(std::move(event));
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't work. `Event<ChildData>` cannot be converted to `Event<Data>`.

Comment: I think OP's question is how they can make something like this passing work. (I also think they want the function parameter to actually be a reference, not by-value.)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I appreciate the effort. It has helped me realise the conceptual and design errors I was about to take on! Realistically I have a lot more thinking and reading to do.